# How to adjust the line number count of a double-column document to start from the title?

Tags: titles, two-column, line-numbering, lineno

I have observed that in latex, the line number count of a single-column document starts from the title, but the line number count of a double-column document starts from the main text. I hope that the line number of a double-column document can also start from the title. Is it, if so, how to modify it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lineno}

\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series\thanks{No procrastination}}
\date{2017\\ December}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department\thanks{I am no longer a member of this department}, Richard Miles University 
\and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}

\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lineno}

\linenumbers
\begin{document}

\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series\thanks{No procrastination}}
\date{2017\\ December}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department\thanks{I am no longer a member of this department}, Richard Miles University 
\and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}

\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: by the way, since I have a large number of latex files that need to do the same, I want this process to be automated.

Answer (score 0):

A workable, though alas not entirely automatic, solution: Insert the instruction

```
\addtocounter{linenumber}{6} % or whatever number is appropriate
```

immediately after `\maketitle`. A caveat: This won't display line numbers for contents of the `\title`, `\author`, and `\date` macros. I trust your readers will manage.

If the `twocolumn` document class option is in effect, I'd load the `lineno` package with the option `switch`, in order to get line numbers displayed to the right of the right-hand columns (and, obviously, to the left of the left-hand columns) on each page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\if@twocolumn
   \usepackage[switch]{lineno}  % load with 'switch' option
   \addtocounter{linenumber}{6} % increment line number as needed
\else
   \usepackage{lineno}
\fi
\makeatother
\linenumbers

\begin{document}

\title{The triangulation of titling data in \\ 
   nonlinear Gaussian fashion via $\rho$ series%
   \thanks{No procrastination}}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department, Richard Miles University%
   \thanks{I am no longer a member of this department}
   \and Richard Row\\ \LaTeX\ Academy}
\date{2017\\ December}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a large number of such files to deal with, so this solution may not be suitable

Comment: No, it is worth keeping.

Comment: @happy - You might have mentioned up front that you "have a large number of such files to deal with."